# Use jquery to select specific element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to do the following below. When I click the < a > tag with the dropdown-toggle class I want to see if the button does not have a class of collasped. If not i will then add the class with jquery

```
<div class="user-controls">
    <button class="navbar-toggle navbar-btn collapsed">
        <span class="icon-reorder"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="hidden-xs"></li>
        <li class="hidden-xs"></li>
        <li class="user-profile">
            <a href="#" class="user-menu dropdown-toggle">Toggle</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
    $('a.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
        var a = $('button.navbar-toggle').hasClass('.collapsed');
        alert(a);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: "If not i will then add the class with jquery" Then no need to check, just add the class in all case: `$('a.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.user-controls').find('button.navbar-toggle').addClass('collapsed');
});`

Comment: It's unclear to me how the title relates to the question...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder right not clear! I think OP wants to target relative button.navbar-toggle to clicked anchor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't include the `.` in the argument to [`hasClass`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass); the argument is just a class name, not a selector. So:

```
$('a.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
    var a = $('button.navbar-toggle').hasClass('collapsed');
    // No dot ----------------------------------^
    alert(a);
});
```

But note that [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass) won't add the class a second time, so you can just call it without checking first if you like. Of course, if you have *other* logic that depends on whether it has the class, then you'd want to use `hasClass`.

---

A. Wolff in a comment on the question said:

> I think OP wants to target relative button.navbar-toggle to clicked anchor

If so, you'd use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to go up to the container, then [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) to find the button within the container:

```
$('a.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
    var a = $(this).closest('.user-controls').find('button.navbar-toggle').hasClass('collapsed');
    alert(a);
});
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, I just noticed that myself. Why dont I use the . dot there but I do for selecting?

Comment: @PierceMcGeough because parameter of hasClass() method is not a selector string but a class name string  http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using the selector syntax for the hasClass method.  ie. you're code has `.hasClass('.collapsed');` instead of `.hasClass('collapsed');`

Answer (score 0):

The following code checks if the element has the 'collapsed' class. If it does not have that class, it adds it.

```
$('a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function(){
  var e = $('button.navbar-toggle');
  if (e.hasClass('collapsed')) {
    alert('The element has the class!');
  }else{
    //This adds the collapsed class to it
    e.addClass('collapsed');
  }
});
```

Comment: The OP wants to set the class on a *different* element.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('a.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){ if($('button.navbar-toggle').hasClass('collapsed'))
 {
      $('button.navbar-toggle').removeClass('collapsed');
 } 
 else{
      $('button.navbar-toggle').addClass('collapsed');} });



        Try this
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your code.  Code only answers are discouraged.